# Increment count every four times

Tags: jquery, count, append

I need to append a group of inputs by clicking a button and their name should get +1 (for the entire group) every time I append a new group.

Instead, I get +1 every input.

I guess one way of getting this is an increment every 4 inputs…?

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var count=0;
$("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("#List").append("Amount: <input type='text' name='Amount1" + (count++) +"' value=0 /><br />Cost: <input type='text' name='Cost1" + (count++) +"' value='0' /><br />Date: <input type='date' name='Date1" + (count++) +"' value='0' /><br />Monthly: <input type='text' name='Monthly1" + (count++) +"' value='0' />");
});
});
</script>
```

I need:

Amount11, Cost11, Date11, Monthly11

Amount12, Cost12, Date12, Monthly12

Amount13, Cost13, Date13, Monthly13

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
    var count=0;
        $("#btn1").click(function(){
            count++;
            $("#List").append("Amount: <input type='text' name='Amount1" + (count) +"' value=0 /><br />Cost: <input type='text' name='Cost1" + (count) +"' value='0' /><br />Date: <input type='date' name='Date1" + (count) +"' value='0' /><br />Monthly: <input type='text' name='Monthly1" + (count) +"' value='0' />");


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do study [Operators](http://javascript.info/tutorial/operators)
try this
Hope it Helps

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){
count++;
$("#List").append("Amount: <input type='text' name='Amount1" + (count)+"'value=0 /><br />Cost: <input type='text' name='Cost1" + (count) +"' value='0' /<br />Date: <input type='date' name='Date1" + (count) +"' value='0' /><br/>Monthly: <input type='text' name='Monthly1" + (count) +"' value='0' />");});
 });
</script>
```